# How to align text and make it black and white in opencv?

Tags: java, python, android, opencv, tesseract

My task is to read the promotional codes from bottle caps and boxes, the caps have different colors and the promotional code is printed in different ways. I want to prepare text with the help of OpenCV on android and read it with the help of a tesseract, tell me please, is it possible to dynamically process different pictures with the help of OpenCV(examples below)? And how can I align the text from the bottle caps in one line so that for example the tesseract can read it qualitatively? Thank.

[image]

[image]

At the moment, it’s possible for me to find the outline of the covers with the help of HSV (but this is not dynamic since the covers have different colors), but the text itself cannot be found and aligned in one line

**upd:**

[hsv_counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI93W.jpg)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

hsv_min = np.array((0, 77, 17), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((208, 255, 255), np.uint8)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn = 'test.jpg'
    img = cv.imread(fn)
    img = cv.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

    hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    thresh = cv.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)
    contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in contours0:
        if len(cnt) > 4:
            ellipse = cv.fitEllipse(cnt)
            cv.ellipse(img, ellipse, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv.imwrite("counter_cap.jpg", img)
    cv.imshow('contours', img)

    cv.waitKey()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[broken_text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIxGj.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

img = cv2.imread("paper.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
src_gray = cv2.blur(gray, (3, 3))
canny_output = cv2.Canny(src_gray, 100, 100 * 2)

ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(canny_output, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
k = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, k)
closing = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(closing, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 1)

k1 = np.ones((4, 4), np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(closing, k1, iterations=2)
small = cv2.resize(erosion, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

# Write image
cv2.imwrite("erosion.jpg", small)

# Path
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

# Recognize text with tesseract for python
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("erosion.jpg")).replace(" ", "")
print("--------- TADAM ITS-------------")
print(result)

# Show image
cv2.imshow("erosion", small)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Could you add some code that you have tried to tackle this problem, so that people can get a better understanding of the issue?

Comment: Hi, thank you, i add some code can you check pls, thx